# Multithreading solution for problem - RxJava vs ExecutorService

Tags: multithreading, rest, rx-java, spring-webflux, executorservice

I am trying to build an application that requires some concurrency since throughput is important.

The steps can be summarized as follows:

1. I have multiple AccountCollector classes. Each one retrieves UserAccounts from two different REST endpoints and combines the responses into a list.
   So

AccountCollector1 -> (AccountRestService1, AccountRestService2) -> return List

AccountCollector2 -> (AccountRestService3, AccountRestService4) -> return List

2. Ideally, the calls within AccountCollector should be concurrent. It should send off the requests and **wait** until both return, then do some processing on the results and notify someone waiting of the result
3. Also ideally, the AccountCollectors should also be running in parallel, they don't depend on each other.

So there are two levels of concurrency, the AccountCollectors running in parallel, and the AccountRestServices running in parallel within each AccountCollector.

I am exploring the best implementation for this.

I started with using Spring Webflux so that the AccountRestService returns a Mono.

I thought RxJava would be ideal for this but I failed to find a way to merge the results in a way where
the merger waits until all REST clients have returned the Mono or at least timedout/failed

So I went ahead and implemented the parallelism using the ExecutorService (pseudocode below).
I also use ExecutorService to achieve parallelism among the AccountCollectors

My questions are as follows:

1. To me the fact that I'm mixing ExecutorService and reactive programming suggests something is wrong. Would that be right?
2. Given that in the future the number of AccountCollectors could grow to hundreds - is the ExecutorService a better solution anyway than RxJava?
3. If not, what would be the best way to merge the calls to the REST clients using RxJava? Any suggestions?

Sorry for the verbose question, I am happy to provide more details. The main thing bothering me is that I started with WebFlux and now I feel I am losing any advantages this gives me.

Thanks!

```
public interface AccountRestService {
    Mono<UserAccount> fetchUserAccount();
}
```

```
public class AccountCollector {

public List<UserAccount> collect() {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        CompletionService<List<UserAccount> pool = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executor);

        ///submit to pool two rest clients
        // get from pool, collect
}

}
```

Comment: Your algorithm is entirely dependent upon the results obtained by asynchronous network services and therefore cannot profitably benefit from local concurrency.

Comment: @michael-berry, Looking at the problem description, I believe all that you needed is nonblocking IO and a way to merge the results when all the remote calls are done. If I were you, I would use Spring Webflux for the nonblocking REST calls and Reactor to [zip] (https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zip-java.util.function.Function-reactor.core.publisher.Mono) those responses together.

Comment: @SanjuThomas You may have tagged me by mistake there - I just edited the question to correct the tags :-)

Comment: @michael-berry, Sorry about that. I can no longer edit my comment. :-)